# What about Newton's potential prevents singularities in the two-body problem?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, centrifugal-force

The solutions to the gravitational two-body problem can be described by conic sections.

In particular, two abstract point masses don't collapse into each other (that is, do not get arbitrarily close to each other) except for the special case where they move on a one dimensional line.

Could this property be deduced without deducing the exact solutions? Is the property connected to more abstract mathematical properties of the Newton potential? Are there more general classes of potential for which this is true and is there a good classification of them?

An even softer question at the end: is the no-collapse property intuitive to you? Personally, I was and still am slightly surprised.

Comment: This due to the centrifugal barrier, because total angular momentum has to be conserved. If they would get infinitesimally close to each other, they would be rotating infinitely fast if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

In the two body problem one can show that angular momentum is conserved and this has two consequences:
-The motion is constrained to a plane;
-One can write an effective potential using the value of the angular momentum (in per unit mass and in the reduced mass frame):

$V_{eff}(r) = - \frac{G\mu}{r} + \frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2}$

We hence have the attractive gravitational potential + a repulsive centrifugal barrier. If the particles come closer together, $r \to 0$, then the centrifugal barrier will have the largest contribution due to the $\frac{1}{r^2}$, hence the repulsive part dominates so that they can't collide. It's like saying that due to energy conservation the particles would begin to rotate infinitely fast around each other.
Like you said, on a line one wouldn't have an angular momentum and the particles would collide.

Comment: Great, this answers the question how to deduce no-collapse without having the explicit solutions. (I cannot upvote for reputation reasons, btw). Moreover, by Noether's theorem, conservation of angular momentum holds for all rotationally invariant potentials, so only one question remains: what makes the effective potential have a limit of positive infinity at $r\to 0$? Does that also hold for all potentials that diverge fast/slow enough at the origin?

Comment: @Fleshman I think the answer and your comment together explain it. The second term diverges more quickly than the first term due to the $1/r^2$ and it is clearly positive ($\mu$ is a positive number).

Comment: Well, the centrifugal term is clearly positive since all quantities are positive and it is the dominating term due to $\frac{1}{r^2} > \frac{1}{r}$ when $r <1$.  
I suppose your second question would be related to having different central potentials? Like adding an attractive $1/r^3$ potential would mean collapse is imminent.

Comment: @NDeWolf I don't know what the maths are to get from the original potential to the $V_{eff}$ in this answer. I suppose of the gravitational potential wasn't $1/r$, then $V_{eff}$ would have a different form too?

Comment: This is usually explained in all texts on the two-body problem. But no, it does not depend on the gravitational potential (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_potential)